# Can you tell how many eigenvectors a matrix has from just the characteristic equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

If the equation has a repeated root, can you tell without evaluating in the matrix if that repeated root corresponds to more than one eigenvector?

Comment: In general, you only know that the geometric multeplicity does not exceed the algebraic multeplicity of an eigenvalue.

Comment: The general topic here is the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), which exists for all square matrices (over $\mathbb C$), unlike diagonalization.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
They have the same characteristic polynomial, but not the same eigenvectors.